# ZFS remove password

Tags: zfs, disk-encryption

I have an encrypted ZFS partition, but I'd like to remove the password not to type any password when booting. Is it possible, ideally without decrypting each file one by one? For instance what happens if I change the password with an empty key?

Answer (score 2):

The encryption is set at dataset creation and cannot be removed.

The password you provide is not the master key used to encrypt data, but a way to access the master key.

By using an empty password you probably need to hit enter anyway... (I've never tried before)

The only way to remove encryption is to send/receive data to a non encrypted dataset.

Comment: Thanks, too bad, so I submitted https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/15987 Actually I just realized that empty passphrase are not even possible (character limit of 8). But maybe it is possible to fake this using keylocation.